# Xamarin Forms Cross platform AdMob not rendering

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, admob, xamarin.forms

Insert the AdMob SDK for Windows Phone 8 in my project and also configured in android project. Android project is working perfectly, but when running the Windows Phone emulator in advertising is not shown.

I checked the capabilities and this all correctly, as follows:

```
ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_AUDIO
ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PLAYBACK
ID_CAP_NETWORKING
ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT
```

Follow my Renderer code:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AdMobView), typeof(AdMobViewRenderer))]

namespace calculotrabalhista.WinPhone
{
    public class AdMobViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<AdMobView, AdView>
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AdMobView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var ad = new AdView
                {
                    Format = AdFormats.Banner,
                    AdUnitID = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx"
                };

                var adRequest = new AdRequest();
#if DEBUG
                adRequest.ForceTesting = true;
#endif


                ad.LoadAd(adRequest);
                SetNativeControl(ad);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Xamarin (Portable) xaml:

```
 <CustomControls:AdMobView Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```

AdMobView class:

```
public class AdMobView : Xamarin.Forms.View
    {
        // enables data binding for the AdMob ad unit id
        [Obsolete]
        public static readonly BindableProperty AdUnitIdProperty = BindableProperty.Create<AdMobView, string>(p => p.AdUnitId, "");

        // holds the AdMob ad unit id
        [Obsolete]
        public string AdUnitId
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)this.GetValue(AdUnitIdProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetValue(AdUnitIdProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

noting that the project android advertising is shown normally. There is no error when running the Windows Phone project and put a breakpoint on the part of the Renderer it fires normally, but nothing appears.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem as you. I added from "*Components*" "*Google Mobile Ads*" and you have to use *BannerView* and the implementation is similar for all platform.

Unless you can have an error in iOS. You can read an implementation for all plarform on this [link](http://puresourcecode.com/dotnet/post/Xamarin-Forms-and-Google-Mobile-Ads-for-iOS).